# TORCH ERROR: return forward_call(*input, **kwargs) AND in _forward_unimplemented raise NotImplementedError NotImplementedError

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nltk, torch

I am trying to build J.A.R.V.I.S using torch, NLP, NN

but I am getting some errors in the training file(train.py)...

below I have put the code of *train.py* and other dependent files!
please help me out!

**ERROR**

```
Training the model...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Utkarsh\OneDrive\Documents\Programs\Python\AI\train.py", line 80, in <module>
    outputs = model(words)
  File "C:\Users\Utkarsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl   
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Utkarsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 201, in _forward_unimplemented
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

**train.py**

```
import numpy as np
import json
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from neural_network import bag_of_words, tokenize, stem
from brain import NeuralNet

with open('intents.json', 'r') as f:
    intents = json.load(f)

all_words = []
tags = []
xy = []

for intent in intents['intents']:
    tag = intent['tag']
    tags.append(tag)

    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        w = tokenize(pattern)
        all_words.extend(w)
        xy.append((w, tag))

ignore_words = [',', '?', '/', '.', '!']
all_words = [stem(w) for w in all_words if w not in ignore_words]
all_words = sorted(set(all_words))
tags = sorted(set(tags))

x_train = []
y_train = []

for (pattern_sentence, tag) in xy:
    bag = bag_of_words(pattern_sentence, all_words)
    x_train.append(bag)

    label = tags.index(tag)
    y_train.append(label)

x_train = np.array(x_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)

num_epochs = 1000
batch_size = 8
learning_rate = 0.001
input_size = len(x_train[0])
hidden_size = 8
output_size = len(tags)

print("Training the model...")


class chatDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.n_samples = len(x_train)
        self.x_data = x_train
        self.y_data = y_train

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.x_data[index], self.y_data[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.n_samples


dataset = chatDataset()

train_loader = DataLoader(
    dataset=dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = NeuralNet(input_size, hidden_size, output_size).to(device=device)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for (words, labels) in train_loader:
        words = words.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(dtype=torch.long).to(device)
        outputs = model(words)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    if (epoch+1) % 100 == 0:
        print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}')

print(f'Final loss: {loss.item():.4f}')

data = {
    "model_state": model.state_dict(),
    "input_size": input_size,
    "hidden_size": hidden_size,
    "output_size": output_size,
    "all_words": all_words,
    "tags": tags
}

FILE = "TrainData.pth"
torch.save(data, FILE)
print(f"Training Complete, File Saved to {FILE}")
```

- other classes and files

**Brain.py**

```
import torch.nn as nn


class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.l1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.l3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forword(self, x):
        out = self.l1(x)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.l2(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.l3(out)
        return out
```

**neural_network.py**

```
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer

Stemmer = PorterStemmer()


def tokenize(sentence):
    return nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)


def stem(word):
    return Stemmer.stem(word.lower())


def bag_of_words(tokenized_sentence, words):
    sentence_word = [stem(word) for word in tokenized_sentence]
    bag = np.zeros(len(words), dtype=np.float32)

    for idx, w in enumerate(words):
        if w in sentence_word:
            bag[idx] = 1
    return bag
```

**intents.json**

```
{
    "intents": [

        {
            "tag": "greeting",
            "patterns": ["hello", "hi", "hey", "what's up", "karen", "hii", "wake up"],
            "responses": ["Hello sir!", "How are you sir", "hello sir, what can I do for you"]
        },
        {
            "tag": "bye",
            "patterns": ["bye", "Good bye", "see you later", "abort", "exit", "quit", "sleep"],
            "responses": ["bye sir!", "Good bye sir, see you later", "see you later, sir"]
        }
       
    ]
}
```

train.py file has the error, neural_network.py and brain.py has some classes which are used in train.py. intents.json file contain the dataset which I have to train using train.py.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo instead of `def forword(self, x)` should be `def forward(self, x)`.

Comment: If the answer is correct, please mark it as a solution.